# Scala can't combine Parser String

Tags: string, list, scala, parsing

I'm writing a parser in Scala and I have one problem.

The bad code is:

```
def workerID: Parser[String] = departementName ~ "=" ~ rep(number | alphabetical)
```

`departementName`, `number` and `alphabetical` are instances of `String`, but `rep()` delivers a `List[String]`, so I can't combine it. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Not sure if i got you right, does `def workerID: Parser[String] = departmentName ~ "=" ~ rep(number | alphabetical) ^^ {
    case dName ~ "=" ~ list => list.mkString
  }` work for you?

Comment: yes thanks i think that's exactly what i wanted. the parsed string can be myowndepartement=abcd010101 now or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def workerID: Parser[String] = departmentName ~ "=" ~ rep(number | alphabetical) ^^ { 
  case dName ~ "=" ~ list => list.mkString 
  //or if you need full string:
  //case dName ~ "=" ~ list => dName + "=" + list.mkString
}
```

does the job.

> the parsed string can be myowndepartement=number010101 now or?

Of course, this code basically folds regular expressions into single parser so if only `departmentName` matches `myowndepartment` you are able to do with `dName` and `list` everything you want.